# Viewing the parse tree/node model/AST in xtext

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, xtext

I'm using xtext to generate an editor for a particular language.  When using the editor for my new language, it has all the lovely xtext features like code-completation and coloring and so on.  What I'd like to be able to do is visualise the structure of the text in my editor.

I know that xtext has an internal AST and a parse tree ( I understand that they call it a `node model') - is there any way of visualising this tree?

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution in xtend (based on the introspection done by default by EObject.toString()):

```
def static String dump(EObject mod_, String indent) {
    var res = indent + mod_.toString.replaceFirst ('.*[.]impl[.](.*)Impl[^(]*', '$1 ')

    for (a :mod_.eCrossReferences)
        res += ' ->' + a.toString().replaceFirst ('.*[.]impl[.](.*)Impl[^(]*', '$1 ')
    res += "\n"
    for (f :mod_.eContents) {
        res += f.dump (indent+"    ")
    }
    return res
}
```

Output from a call such as ***dump(someEObject, '')*** will return:

```
ExpressionModel 
Variable (name: i)
    Plus 
        IntConst (value: 1)
        Plus 
            IntConst (value: 2)
            Plus 
                IntConst (value: 3)
Variable (name: j)
    Plus 
        VarRef  ->Variable (name: i)
        Plus 
            IntConst (value: 4)
            Plus 
                IntConst (value: 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help you: 
https://github.com/OLibutzki/xtext.tools

It offers an outline for the node model and for the semantic model (AST).

Answer (score 1):

You should check the content outline. I have customized mine but I think that the default one reflects the structure of the model.